# How to prove if a mapping is an affine map.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, affine-geometry

Suppose A,( A is not equal to B)B ∈ A2. Is it true that
f: X → centre (A, B, X) is an affine map? Is it bijective?

As per my understanding, we have to show that F(x) = Mx + c to prove the affine map condition(like some translation is happening). But I do not understand how to prove it here. Can anyone please suggest ways to solve it?

Comment: Which center point of the triangle $ABX$ is meant here?

Comment: @Berci I do believe its the centre of the triangle formed by the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed by 'center' you mean the center of mass (intersection of medians), then
$$f(x)=\frac{A+B+x}3=\frac13x+\frac13(A+B)$$
and it has an inverse
$$x\mapsto 3\left(x-\frac{A+B}3\right)\,.$$